# How to get value from autoID in Firebase Database - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code, and I want to display count of values from AutoIds from Firebase Database.
'

```
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!)
    ref.child("users").child(//here should be an auto Id from firebase).observe(DataEventType.value) { snapshot in
        let numberOfusers = snapshot.childrenCount
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)

    }
```

[image]

```
{ 
  "userInfo" : { 
    "baxUvpqL4cMf9p6mqv9czB0FrNN2" : { 
      "dateOfEvent" : "31.10.2021", 
      "guests" : { 
        "-MRK4bbtD4yL4EIsvMnF" : { 
          "age" : "child", 
          "attending" : "attending" 
        }
      }
      ...
```

Тhere will be more auto id's so i need it I need to count all auto id's with value "attending".

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON at `userInfo` (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: {
  "userInfo" : {
    "baxUvpqL4cMf9p6mqv9czB0FrNN2" : {
      "dateOfEvent" : "31.10.2021",
      "guests" : {
        "-MRK4bbtD4yL4EIsvMnF" : {
          "age" : "child",
          "attending" : "attending" 
{
@FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the count of guests who are marked as attending is to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data):

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!)
let query = ref.child("guests").queryOrdered(byChild: "attending").queryEqual(toValue: "attending")
query.observe(.value) { snapshot in
    let numberOfusers = snapshot.childrenCount
    print(snapshot.childrenCount)
}
```